# Barcode-driven overlay for input form operation

Tags: javascript, forms, menu, overlay, barcode

I've had great difficulty googling my idea but I'm sure someone here will lead me in the correct direction. 
I am not a JS programmer but I am contributing ideas to the development of a custom application for my work. I would like to implement a BARCODE driven overlay for a specific Javascript input form so that Users can operate the input form entirely using a barcode wand.
In a best-case scenario, the User would be able to fire the scanner at an input box on the screen and have a combo-box pop-up listing the options to select. The combo box would have ascii in the first column and the corresponding barcode in the second column for selection with the barcode wand. Upon selection, the ascii value would appear in the selected field. In a worst-case scenario, upon form-load, a menu-tree would pop up showing menu items (and corresponding barcodes for selection) at the highest level. Selecting menu items would then launch popups again listing choices and corresponding barcodes so any choice may be selected using the barcode wand. 
Anything in between would certainly be considered. I'm willing to bet there is an off-the-shelf product which can be configured for this purpose. If not, then here is your chance!

Comment: Is this a sales pitch or a question?

Comment: Are you asking, "How would the website know that a 'barcode wand' is 'fired' at the input form?"

Comment: When the form is configured to use the Barcode overlay, it would include barcodes at locations associated with the input fields. Scan the code to open input for the field.

Comment: sbelive - I wish it could be a sales pitch ;-) I just want to understand what can be done and if it is already available to us. But I can tell you that I searched quite a long time and could not see anything like an off-the-shelf solution which would adapt for our use.

Comment: Where would you want the input field to 'open'?